# .Net Client Object Model in Sharepoint returns 500 internal server error while executeQuery

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am trying to see all the lists in my Site using sharepoint Client Object model , following is my code

```
   using (ClientOM.ClientContext ctx =    
            new ClientOM.ClientContext(UrlTextBox.Text))
        {
            //Get the site
            ClientOM.Web site = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(site);
            //Get Lists
            ctx.Load(site.Lists);
            //Query
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
 }
```

The above code throws following Error 
"**The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error**" Tried passing in the credentials too, but didn't work, tried passing DefaultNetworkCredentials too. No luck..

Please advice.

Comment: you probably need to define the credential for accessing the site.
try cc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials or use user name and password  cc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UID, PWD, DOMAIN);

Answer (score 7):

Check everything below and make sure nothing has stopped running.

**1. Check all of your app pools.**
[image: iis]

**2. Check these SharePoint Services.**
[image: sp]

**3. Check the IIS Admin Service.**
[image: services]

Comment: Thank you - my problem was that the "Claims to Windows Token Service" had stopped running.

Comment: I verified each and everything and its set as per you mentioned. But still I am getting error 500. What may I check additionally?

Answer (score 0):

You need a credential before every executeQuery() :

```
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("LoginID", "LoginPW","LoginDomain");
```